# Pandas adding 1's to start of pivot table index values with aggfunc=max

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to sort a dataframe of customer records by email address. Due to multiple values per email address for 'address', 'ids', and other columns, i am using max to return just one value per email address (and the largest id happens to be useful).

An example:

```
d = {'email': ['some_email@email', 'some_email2@email', 'some_email2@email', 'some_email3@email'], 
     'ids': [30, 40, 50, 40], 
     'address': ['address1', 'address2', 'address3', 'address4'],
     'col3': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

table = df.pivot_table(index='email', aggfunc=max)
```

returns this with test data:

```
    address col3    ids
email           
some_email2@email   address3    baz 50
some_email3@email   address4    foo 40
some_email@email    address1    foo 30
```

However, when I use my actual data the email addresses in the result are modified with 1's added to the beginning of the string like this:

```
    address col3    ids
email           
1111some_email2@email   address3    baz 50
1some_email3@email  address4    foo 40
1some_email@email   address1    foo 30
```

I have made a copy of the email data into a new column and it is affected in the same way.

Can someone point me to the issue with either the data itself or how .max works that might cause the 1's to be added to the result?

Thanks!

Comment: Everything looks acceptable to me. Try to check if some_email2@email is in another row. If you only have 1 dimension, you can cross check with `groupby`

Comment: Ah, yes - this seems to be the issue. Missed this in first sweep of the data. Multiple accounts  created with the same email. Multiple emails associated with one account. Going to investigate groupby. Thanks @PTQuoc